# Complex state not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Greeting:

I don't believe I am updating my complex state properly:

```
export const App = () => {
  const [combos, setCombos] = useState({
    combo1: { data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], selected: "" },
    combo2: { data: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12], selected: "" }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <button  onClick={() => setCombos((ps) => ({ ...ps, combo1: { selected: "" }}}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <div>
        Combo 1 has a "data" key:{combos.combo1.hasOwnProperty("data") ? "Yes" :No"}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How do I properly update this state?  Thanks!

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-ellis-qi97k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: There's also typos in the code (missing some closing parentheses).

Comment: `setCombos((ps) => ({ ...ps, combo1: { ...ps.combo1, selected: "" }}))` but the gist of it is to spread the nested `combo1` object to avoid losing its other properties.

Comment: Does this code do what you want it to? If not, what the result are getting? What is the result you expect?

Comment: Thanks Emile...Your responses were helpful.  Alex - please re-read the question.  All the information is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the spread operator also into combo1 property when you set the state. Data property will miss if you update only the selected property.

```
export const App = () => {
  const [combos, setCombos] = useState({
    combo1: { data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], selected: "" },
    combo2: { data: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12], selected: "" }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <button  onClick={() => setCombos((ps) => ({ ...ps, combo1: { ...ps.combo1, selected: "" }}}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <div>
        Combo 1 has a "data" key:{combos.combo1.hasOwnProperty("data") ? "Yes" :No"}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```